# Why does image compression sometimes reduce the size, and sometimes increase the size?

Tags: php, image, compression, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using Imagick to compress images (JPEG mostly), but the results are quite random. For example, check out these results (aproximate numbers, and all JPEG):

1600kb -> 600kb (saved 1000kb)
1000kb -> 1200kb (wasted 200kb)
400kb -> 500kb (wasted 100kb)

Here's the code I used:

```
$image = new Imagick($path);
$image->stripImage(); // remove metadata, though Imagick adds its own, not sure why
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(0); // lossless compression
$image->writeImages($path, true); // writeImages instead of writeImage, in case it's a GIF
```

Comment: That's simply the way it is - different JPEG compression libraries will produce different results. What is your question?

Comment: JPEG images are already compressed.  Adding a pile of metadata by shoving them through another compressor is not likely to be very productive.

Comment: @Pekka웃 My question was in the original question, but someone edited it and turned it into a statement, as usual.

Comment: @Martin removing metadata is a very valid thing to do though if you publish a user-submitted JPG (not saying Imagick is the ideal way to do that, but you *have* to do it, there's so much sensitive stuff that cameras and image editors put in JPG files)

Comment: @MartinJames That's plain wrong, different compressors can achieve different results. Google and Yahoo recommend using special compressors like jpegtran and pngoptim. And I'm not adding metadata, I'm removing it.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question.  Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image recompression will vary depending on the source image files. If the original image was carefully made with good software, ImageMagick might not be able to match it. Simple solution: compare the file sizes of the original and new versions, keep the smaller.

Also, note that the Compression Quality number means different things depending on the file type of the image. In particular, 0 means "worst quality, smallest size" for JPEG, but means "fast compression, not necessarily small" for PNG. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality