# Image Compression Linux CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, command-line

I have been battling around for a while on various compression utilities available in ubuntu.
After reading a lot , i got to know about imagick command.

Imagick has this morgify utility too which compresses png,jpeg images and came up with this approach for compressing image files stored in a folder

```
mogrify  -quality 60 -monitor -strip *
```

I am calling this ommand inside python script.

```
p=subprocess.call("mogrify  -quality 60 -monitor -strip *", shell = True)
```

but these , does not seem to work for image files . i mean insted it increases the size of images.

Is there anything that can be done to always gurantee compression ?

Any help would be of great help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does image compression sometimes reduce the size, and sometimes increase the size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424521/why-does-image-compression-sometimes-reduce-the-size-and-sometimes-increase-the)

Comment: Solution says: Keep the file which has reduced size among original_file & compressed _file.

Comment: It can solve the problem here. but want to know if there's any other utility which can gurantee compression ?